# Does Microsoft index server have a listener?

Tags: windows, search, indexing

I wanted to know if Index server search by Microsoft has  a listener to listen to moves,deletions,rename and modifications in the indexed files?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i found that it does have a listener. But unfortunately im not able to find APIs to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Index server is now called Search Service.

It surfaces an OLE DB data provider.

Setting up Search Service:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23742911/147637

APIs to query the index:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734416(v=ws.10).aspx