# On which OS Search.CollatorDSO is available?

Tags: indexing, filesystems, full-text-search

I am trying to search file system using Search.CollatorDSO:

```
Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties="Application=Windows"
```

On what Windows OS is this provider available by default? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788674/can-i-register-install-search-collatordso-1-manually) it is not installed on Web editions of Windows Server.

If it is not installed can it be installed manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging, it appears the only way to get the ole db provider: Search.CollatorDSO is to enable the Search service in windows OS itself. Installing Search Server from the download does not install it. (Confusing!)

Note that **Windows Search Service**, what this thrad is about, is completely distinct from "Search Server."

[image]